# How to enabled TLS in IXWebSocket for simple client/server application

Tags: c++, websocket, tls1.2, ixwebsocket

I'm attempting to build a simple client/server application in C++ using the IXWebsocket library, using the example code as an example, as shown on this page - https://machinezone.github.io/IXWebSocket/usage/

The code works fine when using an unsecured connection (as denoted by a ws:// url), but I can't get it working at all when using a secured connection (as denoted by a wss:// url).

The website states under the "TLS Support and configuration" section that

> Then, secure sockets are automatically used when connecting to a wss://* url.
> Additional TLS options can be configured by passing a ix::SocketTLSOptions instance to the setTLSOptions on ix::WebSocket (or ix::WebSocketServer or ix::HttpServer)

This implies to me that simply changing the ws:// url to a wss:// url is enough to instruct the application to secure the connection, however this does not work.

When I attempt to connect using a wss:// url, the server returns the following
`WebSocketServer::handleConnection() HTTP status: 400 error: Error reading HTTP request line`

The website goes on to say that

> Additional TLS options can be configured by passing a `ix::SocketTLSOptions` instance to the `setTLSOptions` on `ix::WebSocket` (or `ix::WebSocketServer` or `ix::HttpServer`)

and...

> Specifying certFile and keyFile configures the certificate that will be used to communicate with TLS peers. On a client, this is only necessary for connecting to servers that require a client certificate. On a server, this is necessary for TLS support.

This implies to me that for the server to support TLS, I must provide a cert file, and a key file.

The github repo includes the script `generate_certs.sh` which produces a series of certificates in `pem` format, which should be enough to get things working. Included among them are `selfsigned-client-crt.pem` and `selfsigned-client-key.pem`, which seem like obvious candidates, however they specifically state `client` in the names, which suggests that they should not be used in the server application, rather they belong in the client.

The website also includes the example snippet:

```
webSocket.setTLSOptions({
    .certFile = "path/to/cert/file.pem",
    .keyFile = "path/to/key/file.pem",
    .caFile = "path/to/trust/bundle/file.pem", // as a file, or in memory buffer in PEM format
    .tls = true // required in server mode
});
```

I have attempted to populate the `certFile` and `keyFile` properties, and specified "NONE" for the `caFile` property as explained in the example, however this results in the server application printing `SocketServer::run() tls accept failed: error in handshake : SSL - The connection indicated an EOF` to the console.

What's more, the example snippet listed above states `"path/to/cert/file.pem"` and `"path/to/key/file.pem"` but doesn't explicitly state whether those should be client, or server usage.

The example doesn't come with a complete runnable implementation, and doesn't explain clearly what is needed to make TLS work in this particular form, and I'm at a bit of a loss now.
There is an example application in the github repo, however it includes a number of different variations, all of which are far more complicated than this trivial example, and it is this trivial example that I need to get working so I can understand how to implement this further.

In my server application, I have implemented the following for the TLS options:

```
int port = 8443;

ix::WebSocketServer server(port);
ix::SocketTLSOptions tlsOptions;
tlsOptions.certFile = "certs/selfsigned-client-crt.pem";
tlsOptions.keyFile = "certs/selfsigned-client-key.pem";
tlsOptions.caFile = "NONE";
tlsOptions.tls = true;    //Required for TLS

server.setTLSOptions(tlsOptions);
```

I am pretty sure that the issue in in how I've set up the key and cert files. I have used the client files here, but I also tried generating and signing a server cert and key, which also did not work.

I have even tried using the trusted key and cert for both the client and server applications, and still did not get a working TLS connection (the following files were generated by the generate_cert.sh script -
`selfsigned-client-crt.pem,  selfsigned-client-key.pem, trusted-ca-crt.pem,  trusted-ca-key.pem,  trusted-client-crt.pem, trusted-client-key.pem, trusted-server-crt.pem, trusted-server-key.pem, untrusted-ca-crt.pem, untrusted-ca-key.pem, untrusted-client-crt.pem, untrusted-client-key.pem`

... none of which is a self signed server cert.
What I can gather from the example page is that I need to do the following to get this working.

1. Generate a server cert and key
2. Self sign the cert
3. Specify the cert and key file in the `tlsOptions` on the server
4. Set the tls property in `tlsOptions` to true on the server
5. Set the `caFile` property in `tlsOptions` on the server to "NONE"
6. Set the url in the client to a `wss://` url

But this did not work when I tried it, so there's clearly something I've missed.

All I'm aiming to do for the moment is to use self signed certs so that I can test my client and server, both running on localhost.

If anybody can steer me in the right direction, I'd be immensely grateful. I've been on this for 4 days now and I'm really lost.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this file https://github.com/machinezone/IXWebSocket/blob/master/ws/test_ws.sh / it does a full client + server encrypted exchange.

Note that on macOS there are limitations, but on windows or linux, using mbedtls and openssl everything should work fine.

ps: You will need to supply the same set of certs on the client and on the server.

Comment: Thank you, however you actually already answered this for me on the github page, and you were (as you are now), absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

https://machinezone.github.io/IXWebSocket/build/

-DUSE_TLS=1 will enable TLS support

so I do the following :

mkdir build

cd build

cmake -DUSE_TLS=1 -DUSE_WS=1 ..

works for me